# block iterator, embedded ruby giving me a syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Forgive the noob question but what am I doing wrong?

```
<ul> 
  <% ['red', 'white', 'green'].each do |y| %> 
    <li><%= "#{y} is a color on the Mexican flag" %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I get the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end-of-input
```

EDIT*** this is my full code:

```
require 'erb'

x = 42
template = ERB.new "The value of x is: <%= x %>"
puts template.result(binding)


puts "hello world"


<ul>
<% ['red', 'white', 'green'].each do |y| %> 
    <li><%= "#{y} is a color on the Mexican flag" %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

The error comes on the < from the

```
<ul>
```

line

Comment: which line its giving the error?

Comment: how did you "execute" the example?

Comment: yes which line is error happening?? code looks clean

Comment: Edited the question with which line the error comes in

Comment: I am not getting error with the same code

Comment: We cant use HTML tag in a ruby code.

Comment: Even if remove the ul tag i get the same error for the % ruby tag so i dont think thats the problem? Unless I am misunderstanding

Comment: added a sample code in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cant use HTML tag in a ruby code. Please read http://apidock.com/ruby/ERB , http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html

This explains how to use erb template in Ruby

Here it how it works,

```
['red', 'white', 'green'].each do |y| 
    temp = ERB.new <<-EOF 
        <li><%= "#{y} is a color on the Mexican flag" %></li>
    EOF
    puts temp.result(binding)
end
```

Comment: If i change all my code after (binding) to simply <%= to %> it still gives me same error..

Comment: Edited my answer have you tried with that code sample?

Comment: @user3223348 please accept the answer if you find it useful. Thanks!

Comment: thanks, it works. I still dont understand how erb works though but the code works!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write plain Ruby code and ERB template in the same file. Ruby code should be interpreted by Ruby, and the ERB template should be translated by ERB. You can use here document to quote the template, so that it becomes valid Ruby string, and then parse it with ERB. Just like what you have done in the previous lines.

```
require 'erb'

x = 42
template = ERB.new "The value of x is: <%= x %>"
puts template.result(binding)

puts "hello world"

template = ERB.new <<'END_TEMPLATE'
<ul>
<% ['red', 'white', 'green'].each do |y| %> 
    <li><%= "#{y} is a color on the Mexican flag" %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
END_TEMPLATE
puts template.result(binding)
```

If you're using Rails, for most of the time, you don't have to manipulate ERB module manually. The erb template should be located in `app/views/` folder while the ruby logic should goes to `app/models/` folder or `app/controllers/`, or some other library folder.